# ASP.NET MVC + Forms Authentication + AJAX: Polling action without resetting auth ticket expiration

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, forms-authentication

Is there a way to mark a Controller Action to **not** reset the Forms Authentication ticket sliding expiration?  I want to poll the server every x seconds for new info using ajax but that will effectively prevent the user session from ever expiring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code that renews the ticket is baked inside the [FormsAuthenticationModule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthenticationmodule.aspx) class which is sealed and it is not possible to modify this behavior. This is done by the [RenewTicketIfOld](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.renewticketifold.aspx) method. Anyway [enabling slidingExpiration](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/6745/top-10-application-security-vulnerabilities-in-webconfig-files-part-two/4/) is considered a security vulnerability for your site.